# React-Native - Facing issues while navigating to another screen after fetch api cal

Tags: android, react-native

This is a CRNA app with expo.
On button click in the First screen, I need to first make a fetch API call, capture the response and navigate to the Second screen passing the API response.

The issue I am facing is while I am invoking the fetchData method on button click of 'Create', it successfully navigates to the SecondScreen in the callback function of then(responseJson) but I noticed that even after displaying the SecondScreen, the screen keeps on refreshing automatically and I checked in the logs and saw this log sequence after successful navigation to SecondScreen:

1. In Second Screen -> Log from Second Screen
2. response  -> Log from First Screen
3. responseData: .. -> Log from First Screen
4. Navigate to the Second screen -> Log from First Screen
5. inside fetchData -> Log from First Screen
6. response -> Log from First Screen
7. responseData: .. -> Log from First Screen
8. In Second Screen -> Log from Second Screen

and this goes into a loop.

**First Screen code:**

```
class FirstScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          isSubCreated: false,
          isItemSelected : '',
          subdata: {}
        };
    }

    fetchData(){
        console.log("inside fetchData");

        fetch('http://hostname:port/',{
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {console.log('response'); return response.json();})
            .then((responseJson) => {console.log('responseData: '+responseJson); this.setState({isSubCreated : true, subdata : responseJson}); this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen', {subdata : responseJson});})
            .catch((err) => {console.log(err)}).done();  
    }

    render() {
        const subdata = this.state.subdata;

        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state.params;

        if (this.state.isSubCreated) {
            console.log("Navigate to Second screen");
        }

        return (
            <Container style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.fetchData()}>
                    <Text>Create</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

**Second Screen code:**

```
class SecondScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          subdata: {}
        };
    }

    render() {
        const subdata = this.state.subdata;            
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        console.log("In Second screen");
        return (
            <Container style={styles.container}>
                <Content padder style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.subdata.data}</Text>
                    <View>
                </Content
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why is it coming back to fetch API call of FirstScreen even after successfully navigating to SecondScreen?

**Version:**

react-native@0.50.4

Device: Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered moving fetchData function to the Second screen and putting inside componentDidMount lifecycle method?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Moving fetchData to Second screen and putting inside componentDidMount lifecycle method worked

Comment: Good! Just make sure that if you subscribe to any data by means of event listener inside componentDidMount, remember to delete the event listener inside componentWillUnmount Otherwise you will get error messages.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your suggestion :)